# Dark spot on on Asus laptop screen

Tags: asus-laptop

A few days ago I seen a black mark on my laptop screen. I don't know what it is. It looks like a dead or unstuck pixels, but it looks like it's been hitted in that spot or something. How can I get rid of it? It looks like it's spreading.

Comment: Welcome @user1102795, can you please share a picture of the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give us a screenshot, but a dark spot spreading on the screen (assuming the rest of the screen is showing well) is almost certainly a screen (display) failure.

Try an external monitor to prove this to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Spreading pixel failures from one point is a (almost) failsave sign that there was physical damage. If pixel errors are in appear in random places "all over the screen" it's some other issue.

Try a diagnotic software. In case of stuck pixel it can even revive it. It will give you further information and we might be able to help you further.